# macOS - ssh on WiFi network gives operation timed out

Tags: wifi, ssh

On WiFi, trying to ssh to any server gives this error:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/.../.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

I am able to connect successfully to all servers I have access to with my mobile data. Issue happens only with home WiFi.

Even on WiFi, if I connect to a vpn, then ssh is successful, but without the vpn, it just hangs.

I tried the nmap -Pn command and it gives the state as filtered:

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

Comment: It sounds like your WiFi has some sort of filter blocking outgoing SSH connections, but without more troubleshooting it's hard to say more than that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson do you have any pointers on how to troubleshoot this